# Audio-recorder "start if sound" not working 14.04

Tags: sound, audio-recording

Audio-recorder worked great for me in 13.04.

Now, in 14.04 when I include the option `start if sound` as a `timer` in `audio-recorder`, then `audio-recorder` will just start recording on is own, and as soon as I hit "stop" it will just start again.

I have closed all other applications, and re-installed `audio-recorder`.  Does it just not work in 14.04?

Answer (score 3):

Please file a bug-report on https://launchpad.net/audio-recorder.

It may help if you add time (in seconds) and an audio-level value.

Examples:

```
start if sound 0.4
start if sound 3s 0.4
start if sound 3s 40%
```

Please copy-paste all timer commands (text) to the bug-report.